# bootstrap sticky footer without navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem to stick this footer at the battom of my page but it just refuse to stick when I resize the browser size.

here is the code
http://jsbin.com/piwut/2/

JS Bin

```
<div id="wrap">


  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Sticky footer with fixed  navbar</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.  
  </div> <!-- end container -->
<div id="push"></div>
</div> <!-- end wrap -->

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit"> Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
      /* Sticky footer styles
  -------------------------------------------------- */

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -100px;
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,
  #footer {
    height: 100px;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: black;
  }

  /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've finally found id but here is what i use

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **CSS**:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: If I add this, the footer dissepear once I reduce the browser windows vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -100px;
```

Could you explain what you're trying to achieve with this??

Comment: Well I am new to bootstrap, so I use it for the first time. I'd like to create a full width footer that stick at the battom of the page... the page content may vary as it's generated dynamicaly... and in case the page content is small then the footer should stick at the battom of the browser...